# Creating array from worksheets and using For Each loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, object

I am creating an array from few worksheets and access them using For Each loop. I have accomplished a lot by this approach, and the last small task is to sort the tables on the worksheets.
Can someone please help me to understand why this code is not working and is it possible to achieve this, or I am doing something fundamentally wrong?
If I use the sheet CodeName directly (Sheet1 for example) everything works. For most of the task in the loop I was referring to the sheet's CodeName using just the sh variable and only on few times, if sh was not working sh.CodeName was doing the job, but not for this task.
The Watches window shows as folow:

sh is type Variant/Object/Sheet1
sh.CodeName is type Variant/String and has value "Sheet1"

Any help is highly appreciated in advance.

```
Sub test()

    ' Create array from all worksheets using the Code Names
    Dim arr As Variant
    arr = Array(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3, Sheet4, Sheet5, Sheet6, Sheet7)
    
    Dim sh As Variant
    Dim Table As String
    
    ' Loop trough the sheets
    For Each sh In arr
            
            ' Table 1 of Sheet1 and so on...
            Table = "Table " & Right(sh.CodeName, 1)
    
            sh.ListObjects(Table).Sort. _
                SortFields.Clear
            sh.ListObjects(Table).Sort. _
                SortFields.add key:=Range(Table & "[[#All],[ID]]"), SortOn:= _
                xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            With sh.ListObjects(Table). _
                Sort
                .Header = xlYes
                .MatchCase = False
                .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
                .SortMethod = xlPinYin
                .Apply
            End With
    
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works, if I set up the sheets to match your code.  I notice that you are including a space in the Table names.  This is not the default naming.  So, unless you have changed the table names yourself, there won't be tables of those names on the sheets.

Comment: If you only have one table on each sheet, it would be more reobust to use `sh.ListObjects(1)` instead of  `sh.ListObjects(Table)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/445425/chris-neilsen - You are right, this was just a typo when posting the code. I put the code manually hear in order to use more friendly names.

Comment: Thank you Chris Neilson. I will try it - looks cleaner and make sense.

Answer (score -1):

Excel is finicky when it comes to the focus so you might want to make sure that the sheet you are working on is the active one or set focus to it.
I would try
' Loop trough the sheets
For Each sh In arr
sh.activate

or:
For Each sh In arr
sh.SetFocus

```
' Loop trough the sheets
For Each sh In arr
```